# How to set the username and password for Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: security, raspberry-pi3, password-protection

Is it possible set Username and Password for user login on a Raspberry Pi? If it is, how can I set username and password for raspberry pi 3? Basically, I need to avoid the unauthorized person to enter into raspberry pi.

Comment: Duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67181/how-to-change-a-password

Comment: My case is different from the one which is explained in the above link. Whenever you turn on raspberry pi, after booting it should ask the username and password just like Ubuntu, Windows etc. Just to check the user authentication

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have your Pi configured to auto login to the *pi* account.  You can turn that off in Raspberry menu, Preferences, Raspberry Pi Configuration.  On the System tab, uncheck the Auto Login item.  Now your Pi will give you a login prompt on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Your are using Raspbian OS and wish to cancel the Autologin which is configured by default.
In Terminal type:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

than select

> Boot Options

and than

> Desktop / CLI

and select your favorite option

> Console or Desktop.

After the requested reboot a login screen will appear on startup.

I would also consider changing the default password, which is also possible from the main configuration screen.